# Show the disjoint union of 2 n-manifolds is an n-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

If I have two n-dimensional manifolds X and Y, how do I show that the disjoint union of the two is also an n-dimensional manifold?

## What I did so far

$X \sqcup Y = X \times \{0\} \cup Y\times \{1\} $

From the definition of a manifold there exists a homeomorphism that maps any local subset to an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus $$f_X: X \supset U_X \rightarrow \tilde{U}_X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$$ and similar for Y. If I define a function $f$ that is a composite of these two functions will I not end up with

$$f: X \sqcup Y \supset U_X \times \{0\} \cup U_Y \times \{1\} \rightarrow \tilde{U}_X  \times \{0\} \cup \tilde{U}_Y \times \{1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$$?

Surely the image of $f$ must be of dimension $2n$. How can $f$ possibly be a homeomorphism if it maps from the disjoint union "product" space (which is essentially of dimension $2n$) into a space of dimension $n$.

## Edit:

I think this question is more about the definition of a disjoint union. I always thought if $X = \{1,2\}$ and $Y = \{3,4\}$ then $X \sqcup Y = \{(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1)\}$ is essentially like a more primitive version of an outer product in a  vector space.

Comment: A useful answer would depend very much on your definition of manifold. If it is a "nice" topological space that is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then there is no problem: you have charts on one, you have charts on the other, so you have charts on the disjoint union. The charts of the two manifolds never intersect, so you have smoothness for free, there is really nothing to check.

Comment: Does the disjoint union mean that locally my new manifold is of a higher dimension or not? If not, how can we have a homeomorphism? Also yes I am using that as my definition of manifold. See the first equation.

Comment: No, it has the same dimension. A homeomorphism of what? You only have local homeomorphisms. The points of the disjoint union are the points of one manifold AND ("separately") the points of the other. For each of them, they have a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (because they live on a manifold)

Comment: In other words: a subset of the disjoint union is open if and only if it is a union of an open set of one side and an open set of the other side. In particular, the topology of the disjoint union contains the topologies of the two manifolds. So you can just take the old charts as charts for the disjoint union.

Comment: Suppose I look at a chart on $X$ homeomorphic to a neighbourhood around the origin. Now I look at another chart on $Y$ that also maps to a neighbourhood around the origin. Would the disjoint union of the two charts be homeomorphic to a neighbourhood around the origin?

Comment: No, it will be homeomorphic to the disjoint union of two neighborhoods around the origin ;) but you do not need to consider disjoint unions of charts of $X$ and charts of $Y$ to make new charts: you just take the charts of $X$ AND the charts of $Y$

Comment: As for your definition of a disjoint union: it is perfectly correct, but remember that the second coordinate is only a means to remember which space this point comes from. As long as there is no confusion possible, you could also write $\{1,2\} \sqcup \{3,4\} = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: A small correction to my above comment: of course, a disjoint union of two neighborhoods of the origin IS (homeomorphic to)a neighborhood of the origin, in a similar way as you did in your answer

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I understand where my mental block was. An outer product of the real line with the real line is effectively an uncountable number of disjoint unions of the real line with itself while the disjoint union can be mapped 1 to 1 back into the real line.

Here is very simple map from the space of $\mathbb{R}^n \sqcup \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ since we can easily map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow I^n = (-1,1)^n $ the n dimensional extended open unit interval. Since this is so we can obviously map the second $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow I^n = (-1,1)^n + a$ where $a$ is a constant of dimension $n$ with magnitude $>1$. Thus we have two disjoint open sets mapped to that are both a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ hence we complete the proof.

Notice this fails if we have an uncountable number of disjoint unions since there isn't enough "space" to fit all the $I^n$ without overlapping. This is a very non technical answer but I think it helps visualize the difference between the outer product and disjoint union at least.

Comment: "... while the disjoint union can be mapped" $2:1$ back into the real line. The disjoint union is two lines. The product is a plane.

Comment: It is a very correct answer, I'd say. The problem is exactly that we tend to think of objects as embedded in some space, so that there is only one interval $[-1,1]$, for instance. But in reality we can consider many distinct copies of the same space / interval / ...

Comment: One usually does not consider uncountable unions of manifolds because they are not second countable anymore (which is sometimes a requirement in the definition of manifold). But you can consider the disjoint union of uncountably many topological spaces (whether they are copies of the same space or not) and put a very natural topology on it. If you have time, it might be worth having a look at [this](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/topologies.pdf)